# Share Link to Whatsapp not showing meta tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, share

I've been try to make sharer link to Whatsapp but not working (not showing description, title,image) though i was put og and meta tags. Is Whatsapp has debugger like facebook share debugger ?

here is my meta code :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <!-- blumtambahan --><meta name="keywords" content="Berita, News, Schoolmedia, news schoolmedia, news sm, sm news, sm, Kriminal, Hoaks, Opini, Artikel, Video, Foto, Galeri, Alumni, Web Sekolah, Sekolah, Website, Internet, Situs, CMS Sekolah, Web Sekolah, Website Sekolah Gratis, Website Sekolah, Aplikasi Sekolah, PPDB Online, PSB Online, PSB Online Gratis, Penerimaan Siswa Baru Online, Raport Online, Kurikulum 2013, SD, SMP, SMA, Aliyah, MTs, SMK, Liputan Kusus, Newsfeed, Tokoh, Indeks, layanan, publik, jurnal akademik, ja, scoin, rpp, sosial media, sosmed, sch, pitakon, tes online, try out, usbk, belajar, quipper, ruang guru, edmodo, tanyab, edukasi, mau, materi ajar dan ujian, user management, um, les private">

  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="news.schoolmedia.id" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Judul Bla bla bla">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://news.schoolmedia.id/uploads/konten/4337eb42fd10918d23e0cc18f90e2511945a1fa9/pendidikan_online_-_pixabay.jpg">
  <meta property="og:description" content="SCHOOLMEDIA NEWS, Jakarta - Kementerian Riset, Teknologi dan Pendidikan Tinggi (Kemristekdikti)">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://news.schoolmedia.id/berita/Kemristekdikti-Publikasi-Internasional-Indonesia-Terbanyak-di-ASEAN-757">
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="650" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="366" />
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://news.schoolmedia.id/berita/Kemristekdikti-Publikasi-Internasional-Indonesia-Terbanyak-di-ASEAN-757"/>

  <meta itemprop="name" content="News Schoolmedia" />
  <meta itemprop="description" content="SCHOOLMEDIA NEWS, Jakarta - Kementerian Riset, Teknologi dan Pendidikan Tinggi (Kemristekdikti)" />

  <meta name="googlebot-news" content="index,follow" />
  <meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow, snippet, imageindex" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow, snippet, imageindex" />
  <meta name="teoma" content="index, follow, snippet, imageindex" />
  <meta name="msnbot" content="index, follow, snippet, imageindex" />
  <meta name="slurp" content="index, follow, snippet, imageindex" />

  <meta name="subject" content="Situs Berita Sekolah">
  <meta name="copyright" content="News Schoolmedia">
  <meta name="author" content="Schoolmedia">
  <meta name="language" content="Indonesian">
  <meta name="geo.country" content="id" />
  <meta name="geo.placename" content="Indonesia" />

  <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="In-Id" />
  <meta http-equiv="Copyright" content="News Schoolmedia" />


  <title>Judul Bla bla bla</title>
```

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: When using opengraph meta tags try the [Facebook URL linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and refresh the cache (sometimes better do twice).

Comment: yeah, i've been try it , but still didn't work

Comment: "Did not work" is the best problem description ever. What does the Scraper output?

Comment: here is the output https://i.postimg.cc/C1kVDNH1/4125c480-66f1-442d-9a7a-42eaad959f05.jpg